# XlsxWriter chart series direct from data without worksheet refs

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is there a mechanism is `XlsxWriter` to load data directly into a new series without referencing worksheet cell?  I am looking to do something like this:

```
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       'Pie sales data',
    'categories': ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Pecan'],
    'values':     [1, 3, 1]
})
```

Comment: No. That isn’t supported.